# staleelement reference exception in selenium webdriver for VBA

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Please help
I am trying to run a VBA code using selenium chrome driver.

My target is to

```
Line 1:select a Xpath(control) and enter a value 
Line 2:Click on the value that comes below 
Line 3:Clear Xpath(control) value 
Line 4: select a Xpath(control) and enter a value
Line 5:Click on the value that comes below 
Line 6:Clear Xpath(control) value
```

Line 5 throws an error Runtime error 10 staleelement reference exception( the element that needs to be clicked has same path value as in line 2)

```
Sub Test()

    Dim driver As ChromeDriver

    Dim a1 As String
    Dim b1 As String

    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    driver.Get ("https:mytestenvironment.in")

    a1 = "Short ID"
    b1 = "CHL Type of leave"

    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='export-custom-columns-autocomplete']/ul/input").SendKeys a1 '- Line1
    On Error GoTo -1
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='export-custom-columns-autocomplete']/ul/div/li[2]").Click '-Line 2
    On Error GoTo -1
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='export-custom-columns-autocomplete']/ul/input").Clear '-Line 3
    On Error GoTo -1
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='export-custom-columns-autocomplete']/ul/input").SendKeys b1 '-Line 4
    On Error GoTo -1
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='export-custom-columns-autocomplete']/ul/div/li[2]").Click '-Line - 5
    On Error GoTo -1
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='export-custom-columns-autocomplete']/ul/input").Clear '-Line - 6

End Sub
```

However after I debug and re run it runs good

I tried adding on error statement but no results

Sample code:

```
Sub Test()
    
    Dim driver As ChromeDriver
    
    Dim a1 As String
    Dim b1 As String
    
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    driver.Get ("https:mytestenvironment.in")
    
    a1 = "Short ID"
    b1 = "CHL Type of leave"
    
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='export-custom-columns-autocomplete']/ul/input").SendKeys a1
    On Error GoTo -1
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='export-custom-columns-autocomplete']/ul/div/li[2]").Click
    On Error GoTo -1
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='export-custom-columns-autocomplete']/ul/input").Clear
    On Error GoTo -1
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='export-custom-columns-autocomplete']/ul/input").SendKeys b1
    On Error GoTo -1
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='export-custom-columns-autocomplete']/ul/div/li[2]").Click
    On Error GoTo -1
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='export-custom-columns-autocomplete']/ul/input").Clear
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Stale Element exception means element is there on page but driver instance could not interact with that

There are 2 ways to resolve this
1.Refresh page
2.Do loop until element is click

Comment: If I refresh the page the element is lost as step 2 is the one that makes element in step 3 visible and Loop is also not working