EXCEL VBA Selenium click svg/xlink:href
So I started with Selenium (Chromedriver) yesterday, and while I just want to automate some easy things, my knowledge and the web developers of the web reporting we are using are giving me a big headache.
This is the html code with the clickable svg. The awesome part is, that the ID is not static.

<div class="dx-item dx-tile" style="width: 65px; height: 65px; left: 130px; top: 0px;" id="dx-517927a9-664c-6b1f-71fe-1c9d526443c9">
    <div class="dx-item-content dx-tile-content">
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="#dx-dashboard-export-to-excel"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

I tried copying the CSS Selector and XPath but it always includes the ID.
I also tried this approach as it worked well in other ocassions. There are 2 other svg elements to the left.
Dim List As Selenium.WebElements
Set List = Chrome.FindElementsByClass("dx-item-content dx-tile-content")

If List Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "failed."
'    Exit Sub
End If

List(3).Click

but its obviously not working, as it can only contain 1 class at a time.
I also tried:
Chrome.FindElementByCss("[svg = '#dx-dashboard-export-to-excel']").Click
also tried xlink:href = but also didnt work
Chrome.FindElementsByTag ("svg")
But so far nothing worked at all.
I already looked at all the Locator Strategies but i am too much of a noob and there doesnt seem to be that much coverage on VBA in particular.
Appreciate any help

Instead of
.FindElementsByClass("dx-item-content dx-tile-content")

which is expecting a single class and is being passed 2 classes, use a CSS selector
.FindElementByCss(".dx-item-content.dx-tile-content")


Unless you have a requirement to use Excel, I would choose another language because Excel+Selenium is poorly documented and maintained.
Having said that, your question is more about locators than the programming language/syntax so you can google locator types, read blogs for any other language and you'll find locator info that's useful no matter the language that you use.

Thank you, i tried a few things now. I tried: Set List = Chrome.FindElementsByCss(".dx-item.dx-tile") but the list has no interactable elements. I also tried: 'Chrome.FindElementByXPath("//[name()='use' and @='#dx-dashboard-export-to-excel']").ScrollIntoView
'Chrome.FindElementByXPath("//[name()='use' and @='#dx-dashboard-export-to-excel']").Click but this gives me the error, that the click would actually go to ".dx-item-content.dx-tile-content". But thank you very much for the help, looking for locators independently is already a big step up

while this helped I stillt cant figure out a way to make it work. atm this code is throwing runtime error 10. Set List = Chrome.FindElementsByCss(".dx-item.dx-tile") -> List(3).click but if i manually rerun it it works, all the time on the 2nd try, so i will just implement a loop as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370069/staleelement-reference-exception-in-selenium-webdriver-for-vba not very satisfying, but i hope it will work. I did upvote, but its not counting as I dont have enough points.

I think what you probably need is the equivalent of a WebDriverWait in VBA but it doesn't exist. I did find this link where someone implemented something similar in the accepted answer that you could try... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956889/selenium-webdriver-vba-explicit-wait

perfect analysis, i was already using Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")) but i  used it at the wrong place and also failed to realize that when i use .scrollintoview the popup window closes again. everything is running smooth now

Application.Wait() is the equivalent of a sleep in other languages and is considered a "dumb" wait in that it just waits for X seconds, no matter what. What you need is the equivalent of a WebDriverWait, a "smart" wait. It waits for a condition, e.g. an element to be clickable or visible, and only stops long enough for the condition to be true.

Thanks for your persistence! I changed it to that and i am also using the JS script by florentbr. What still suprises me is that even if I wait for the svg to be clickable i still have to perform 2 clicks while with a mouse i will only need 1. I noticed the element's class is changing to sth. like "dx-tile-hover" when the mouse is on top, so I guess I have to trigger that before i can click it. Thanks a lot Jeff!

This is actually working!
Dim List As Selenium.WebElements Set List = Chrome.FindElementsByCss(".dx-item.dx-tile")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

Do
    If List(3).IsDisplayed = True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        List(3).Click
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        Chrome.FindElementByClass("dx-button-content").Click
        On Error Resume Next
        List(3).Click
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If Loop Until Chrome.FindElementByCss("#ctl00_MainContent_ASPxSplitter1_ASPxDashboardViewer
> div > div.dx-overlay-wrapper.dx-popup-wrapper.dx-dashboard-form-wrapper.dx-designer-viewport.dx-overlay-shader
> div > div.dx-popup-bottom > div > div.dx-widget.dx-button.dx-button-mode-contained.dx-button-default.dx-button-has-text.undefined").IsDisplayed
= True

actually it was as easy as:
Chrome.FindElementByCss("#ctl00_MainContent_ASPxSplitter1_ASPxDashboardViewer > div > div.dx-dashboard-surface > dashboard-docking-layout > div.dx-dashboard-layout-container.dx-scrollable.dx-scrollview.dx-visibility-change-handler.dx-scrollable-undefined.dx-scrollable-simulated > div.dx-scrollable-wrapper > div > div.dx-scrollable-content > div.dx-scrollview-content > div > dx-layout-item > div > div > div > dx-layout-item > div > div > div > dx-layout-item > div > dx-dashboard-layout-group > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > dx-layout-item:nth-child(2) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > dx-layout-item > div > div.dx-layout-item-container.dx-dashboard-item-container.dx-dashboard-group-item-child > div.dx-dashboard-caption-toolbar.dx-toolbar.dx-widget.dx-visibility-change-handler.dx-collection > div > div.dx-toolbar-after > div:nth-child(1)").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

Dim List As Selenium.WebElements
Set List = Chrome.FindElementsByCss(".dx-item.dx-tile")

List(3).Click

    

